# Advertising Platform CMS

Tags: advertising, cms, marketing, affiliate

I would like to know if there is any "advertising platform" cms arround, in order to host affiliate marketing tags / banners / etc

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Open-source "ad server solution" [Open X](http://www.openx.org/) is incredibly powerful, but might have a bit too much of a learning curve if all you're looking to do is affiliate banners.

Answer (score 2):

As an out-of-the-box suggestion, [Kajabi](http://get.kajabi.com/sales_pages/1240) is a hosted service. I haven't used it, but it looks like it could be worth a look if it fits your product and business model.  Otherwise, you could use a CMS like Joomla or Wordpress and integrate with an affiliate service. [Zferral](http://zferral.com/) and [HasOffers](http://www.hasoffers.com/) are two such affiliate services you could use. Personally, I recommend the second method.

Comment: Kajabi looks terrible. A sales funnel is not just a linear sequence of pages that you send customers through. Get a real CRM or SFA app if you want to increase conversion rates and automate sales processes. You don't need a substandard CMS that makes your site look spammy and ghetto. Zferral looks promising though.

Comment: Depending on what you're selling, I might be inclined to agree with you, Lèse majesté. However, I do think that Kajabi might be worth a try for certain types of products and businesses. If you have more of an e-commerce store setup with multiple products and categories, it probably is a terrible choice. But if you have one or two products that are conducive to that type of funnel, it might serve a purpose. Like I said, though, I haven't tried it, so I can't speak to its effectiveness. I probably wouldn't use it myself, but I thought I would throw it out there as an out-of-the-box suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend finding a third party module and using one of the mainstream CMS platforms out there, such as Drupal, Jooma & Wordpress.  You can in addition integrate Google Ads if that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

is a CMS really necessary for that?  Most affiliate systems have this functionality built in.  In a custom coded (asp, php, rails, ) solution this would be very easy to setup and manage.